# Python 3.9 glob.iglob going in infinite searching for files

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

Below code is going in endless loop as getting stuck in some **/proc/self.... paths.**

After killing the execution, when I tried to check the path then found no matching folder with this random number and during processing also, folder is there but  not have any JAR file in it (which is given in search pattern).

Also, when trying to search using find on linux console then it also not have this path in search output as in actual this path does not have the files of given pattern ->
find . -name "*test*.jar" 2>/dev/null

```
path = "/"  
filepattern = "*test*.jar"  
assert os.path.exists(path), "I did not find the path " + str(path)
path = path.rstrip("/")
tocheck = (f'{path}/**/{filepattern}')
searched_file_list = glob.iglob(tocheck, recursive=True)
print(searched_file_list)
for file in searched_file_list:
    print(f'{file}')
```

```
**In print getting path of /proc/self...** location but in actual, this location does not have the files of given pattern *test*.jar: - 

/proc/self/task/3488552/root/proc/self/task/3488552/root/proc/self/task/3488552/root/proc/self/task/3488552/root/proc/self/task/3488552/root/proc/self/task/3488552/root/proc/self/task/3488552/root/proc/self/task/3488552/root/proc/self/task/3488552/root/proc/self/task/3488552/root/proc/self/task/3488552/root/proc/self/task/3488552/root/proc/self/task/3488552/root/proc/self/task/3488552/root/proc/self/task/3488552/root/proc/self/task/3488552/root/proc/self/task/3488552/root/proc/self/task/3488552/root/proc/self/task/3488552/root/proc/self/task/3488552/root/opt/disk1/apps/test/mss-test-e16/tars/lib/test-check-whole-1.1.34-shaded.jar 

/proc/self/task/3488552/root/proc/self/task/3488552/root/proc/self/task/3488552/root/proc/self/task/3488552/root/proc/self/task/3488552/root/proc/self/task/3488552/root/proc/self/task/3488552/root/proc/self/task/3488552/root/proc/self/task/3488552/root/proc/self/task/3488552/root/proc/self/task/3488552/root/proc/self/task/3488552/root/proc/self/task/3488552/root/proc/self/task/3488552/root/proc/self/task/3488552/root/proc/self/task/3488552/root/proc/self/task/3488552/root/proc/self/task/3488552/root/proc/self/task/3488552/root/proc/704344/task/704344/root/proc/704344/task/704347/root/opt/disk1/apps/test/mss-test-e16/tars/lib/test-check-whole-1.1.34-shaded.jar
```

Comment: Please anyone can advice on this.

@Henry
ElderFuthark platipus_on_fire Mark Ransom Jon Clements -- Please can either of you expert also suggest on this.

Comment: Please anyone can advice on this. @Henry ElderFuthark platipus_on_fire Mark Ransom Jon Clements -- Please can either of you expert also suggest on this. –

Comment: @honorius .... Please advice on this...Thanks!